# Microsoft Windows RPC (135/tcp) security risks

Tags: windows, known-vulnerabilities

I was running a vulnerability scan against a Windows Server of mine, TCP port 135.
I got the following output:

> By sending a Lookup request to the portmapper TCP 135 it was possible
>   to enumerate the Distributed Computing Environment services running on
>   the remote port. Using this information it is possible to connect and
>   bind to each service by sending an RPC request to the remote
>   port/pipe.

So now I have the following questions:

- How can someone connect and bind to each service? What is the command/tool to use, and does it require authentication?
- What are the security risks of having this service running, if any?

Comment: you need to authenticate in order to get information from services via RPC.

Comment: Older versions of Windows allowed null enumeration--collection of possibly dangerous information about the server without authenticating. http://www.sheetaljoseph.org/scribblings/enumeration.pdf is a decent overview of the dangers from that era.

Comment: @user502 - your comment should be an answer.

Comment: That did sorta cross the information-content threshhold for a full answer.  Unfortunately, it was wrong--139 and 445 were the null enum risks on pre-Windows XP SP2 and Windows 2003 SP1 systems.  DCE/RPC endpoint mapping is different, it'll give you information like this: http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/DCERPC_Endpoint_Mapper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- How can someone connect and bind to each service? What is the command/tool to use, and does it require authentication?

The `net use` command, browsing network shares, or any other SMB-related command will make use of these services.

- What are the security risks of having this service running, if any?

It's often a necessary service to have running as it provides the backbone of a great deal of Windows network sharing services. I wouldn't be concerned so much on it running as I would be concerned if it were exposed outside your network. I believe service enumeration and possible undocumented exploits are the two current risks. Because this is a remote procedure call service, it does have some of the same excitement as any application service -- think of requests passed there in terms of a web query. They ask for a service (page) and pass certain relevant parameters (GET or POST options). Something on the service's back-end runs and returns a result.

- See also http://isc.sans.edu/port.html?port=135